# How to display Material UI drawer with top margin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement Material UI drawer with some top margin instead of starting from very top of the page, but its not happening, i have tried applying `marginTop` but its not happening. here is the codeSandBox link [Drawer](https://codesandbox.io/s/invisible-backdrop-tgco0?fontsize=14&file=/demo.js).

How to apply top margin?

Comment: Hello. Let me see i get you. You want to apply margin-top on temporary drawer right?

Comment: Why not use clipped drawer https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#ClippedDrawer.js

Comment: @EdsonMagombe yes.

Comment: Why not use clipped drawer https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#ClippedDrawer.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `marginTop` to `drawerPaper` instead

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  drawerPaper: {
    marginTop: "50px"
  }
});
```

```
const classes = useStyles();

<Drawer
  classes={{
    paper: classes.drawerPaper
  }}
>
  {sideList("left")}
</Drawer>
```

Comment: Thanks brijesh for sharing this. I updated ` drawerPaper: {
        marginTop: "3.8%"
    }` and its coming up where i need but when its not resposive, basically its not behaving same in different different screens. How to solve this?

Comment: @Lara I don't see any issues with responsiveness, perhaps it's being affected by your global theming. Try setting the `marginTop` to an absolute unit like `100px`.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a breaking change in MUI v5 https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/#material-ui-v5-and-mui-styles for makeStyles.

Answer (score -1):

In MUI V5:

```
       <Drawer
            anchor={'top'}
            open={isOpen}
            hideBackdrop
            onClose={() => onClose()}
            sx={{
              '&.MuiDrawer-root .MuiDrawer-paper': { marginTop: '67px' },
            }}
          >
            {children}
          </Drawer>
```